# Value error in Python: oo many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe(dfooc3) with about 20k rows. I want to split this into 38 dataframes
Please note- I cannot use the executemany function to write this.

I am trying to write this df to my warehouse from python. I tried-

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('dsn=SNOWFLAKE_ENGINEER_SA;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
    import numpy as np
    a, b, c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12 = np.array_split(dfooc3, 38)
    for index, row in a, b, c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sf.claim(MemberId,ProgramCode,PolicyNumber,PolicyHolderName,StateCode) values(?,    ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  )",row.MemberId,row.ProgramCode,row.PolicyNumber,row.PolicyHolderName,row.StateCode,)    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()  
    Traceback:
    line 1, in <cell line: 1>
        for index, row in a, b, c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12.iterrows():
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Surely there must be some more elegant approach than using 38 obscurely named variables covering the entire alphabet and some (not to mention copy-pasting that ridiculous 38-tuple over and over). That hurts to even look at.

Comment: @DanMašek :D the elegant approach is exactly what im looking for on here haha

Comment: What exactly does `np.array_split(dfooc3, 38)` produce?  38 arrays, but how long are each of them?  The following iteration/unpacking only works if all those arrays have length 2.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the right way to loop over multiple objects and a variable name for each dataframe manually is really a bad idea.

Try this instead:

```
for df in np.array_split(dfooc3, 38):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        ...
```

Comment: this is running since 2 hours. is there a faster way to do this? Just waiting for the output so i can mark this as correct

Comment: There is surely a faster way, but I would need to check the dataframes. Plus, it looks you have a connection to a database, that could be the bottleneck. Depending on you infrastructure, you could run async calls to the database. You need to design the script accordingly.

Comment: this is still running. definitely have to find an alternative. Yes i am writing my df to a snowflake table.